# django nose test, How to initialize a setup before any tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, nose

I'm using django_nose for test django apps,

simply run `python manage.py test`

But, I wanna do a setup before any tests.

For example, create a file before test start. and then all the tests will using this file.

How to do this?
please help

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [nose docs](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-modules), Test modules offer module-level setup and teardown; define the method `setup`, `setup_module`, `setUp` or `setUpModule` for setup. for e.g. [`setup_module()` function](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_doctest_fixtures/doctest_fixtures.html): runs before anything else in the file